# How to stop Doctrine from returning a primary key for every query

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I am kind of annoyed at Doctrine for returning primary keys in each and every query even though I don't want it to. Is there anyway to stop this ? coz I don't really want those damn primary keys along with my doctrine query results.

A query for instance that I have is:

```
$getAllDatesForUserQuery = $this->createQuery('s')
    ->select('s.datename')
    ->where('s.userid = ?',3)
    ->setHydrationMode(Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY) ;
```

In this situation, it retrieves all the datenames as it should, but also happily returns the primary key column value. I DON"T WANT IT.

Is it me? or is it Doctrine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a case like this where you want a simple array and only have a single field being selected, the answer is the `Single Scalar Hydration` mode. Use it like this:

```
$q = $this->createQuery('s')
->select('s.datename')
->where('s.userid = ?',3)
->setHydrationMode(Doctrine::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR);
```

You should find that the query will return a simple one-dimensional array containing only the value(s) you wanted.

Comment: well, how about we complicate this a little bit, suppose I want to return multiple fields, but not the primary key, it will return the primary key as well in this case right. Also, if there are joins being conducted, both primary keys for the two tables will be returned, how is this avoided ?

Comment: have you tried [Scalar Hydration](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#scalar-hydration)?